# Using Strategy Pattern for supporting uploading file from multiple sources

Tags: design-patterns, file-upload, factory-pattern, strategy-pattern, system-design

I am working on a web app project which requires me to refactor file uploading feature. Our file uploading feature supports multiple sources of uploading file, such **git repo**, **nexus URL**, **zip files** and we also want to support more such as perforce in the future. In the current implementation, the application has multiple endpoints to handle different methods such as `getNexusFile()`, `getGitFile()`, `getZipFile()`; under each method, there is implementation for retrieving files from specified source.

My idea is to merge all these methods into one method called `getUploadFile()` by using **Strategy Pattern**.  As in the Strategy pattern, 
algorithms could be selected at runtime, so files uploaded from different sources could be treated indifferently after I specify the right strategy.  For every source, I’ll create a strategy for it.

***My question is: is that a good practice of design pattern?  Is there any better approach to model this question?***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strategy pattern is a valid approach for this problem.

```
Class SomeClass {
  private FileUploader fileUploader;
}

Interface FileUploader {
     public void uploadFile();
}

Class GitFileUploader implements FileUploader{
     public void uploadFile() {//Implementation for Git File Upload}
}

Class NexusFileUploader implements FileUploader {
     public void uploadFile() { //Implementation for Nexus }
}
```

You can add more implementations of `FileUploader` as needed.

Comment: This only makes sense if the concrete `FileUploader` is not modified during the lifetime of the `SomeClass` object. If a single `SomeClass` object is expected to upload different files from different sources, using a *Factory Method* or *Abstract Factory* might be more appropriate.